# Matlab color-coded plot of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, graphics

Say I have a matrix like

```
A= [0 -50 2;
    0 -18 7;
    0  13 3;
    1 -50 3;
    1 -18 5;
    1  13 1;]
```

In reality, this matrix is larger but the first column is counting upwards while the second one is repetitive. Now I want to plot this colour-coded to get a result like e.g. [this one](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/images/heat-map/heat-map.png), i.e. A(:,1) and A(:,2) are the x and y axes, respectively.

How would you do that? I've tried `pcolor`, `imagesc` and others but no luck so far. Sorry if this is a duplicate - I have searched stackoverflow and other websites but did not find anything that I could use.

Comment: `imagesc` and `pcolor` are the way to do it. Please show your code, or rather a minimal example that reproduces the problem, so that you can get help

Comment: When you say `A(:,2)` is the y axis, do you mean y axis is sampled at -50, -18 and -13 in your example?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, exactly.

Comment: That means you need to set up array axes as `x=unique(A(:,1))` and`x=unique(A(:,2))`, and then fill a matrix with the values from the 3rd column at appropriate places. This matrix you can plot using the two functions you tried.

Comment: I guess you mean `y=unique(A(:,2))`?
I just tried that:
    ```x=unique(A(:,1));
    y=unique(A(:,2));
    figure
    imagesc(x,y,A(:,3))```

But unfortunately this doesn't solve it.

Comment: No, that doesn't solve it. Are the first two columns always in the same order? That is, the y column visits each of the sample points in sequence for the first x coordinate, then again the same points for the second x coordinate, etc.? That makes it easier, you can just `reshape` the third column to the right sizes. If there are missing values, or if the order is not always preserved, then things get much more complicated.

Comment: "That is, the y column visits each of the sample points in sequence for the first x coordinate, then again the same points for the second x coordinate, etc.?" - yes, that is correct and there are no missing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works even if the grid defined by the *x* and *y* columns has **missing** or **repeated** entries. In the first case the result will contain no colour for the missing values (just the axis background), and in the second case the values will be overwritten.

The code generates a matrix from the data where the missing entries are marked with `NaN`, and then displays it using [`pcolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html), which ignores `NaN` entries. Because of how this function works, a column and a row need to be added to the matrix before displaying.

```
A = [0 -50 2;
     0 -18 7;
     0  13 3;
     1 -50 3;
     1 -50 5; 
     1  13 1] % example. Entry (1,-50) is repeated, and entry (1,-18) is missing
[ux, ~, ind_x] = unique(A(:,1)); % unique values of x and indices to them
[uy, ~, ind_y] = unique(A(:,2)); % same for y
B = NaN(numel(uy), numel(ux)); % row is y, column is x
B(ind_y + size(B,1)*(ind_x-1)) = A(:,3); % linear indexing to fill the values into B
pcolor([B NaN(size(B,1),1); NaN(1,size(B,2)+1)]) % pcolor discards last row and column
axis xy
xticks((1:numel(ux))+0.5), xticklabels(ux)
yticks((1:numel(uy))+0.5), yticklabels(uy)
colorbar
```

[image]

Comment: I am having a really hard time understanding what magic you're doing there, mate, but it works perfectly - thank you so much!

Comment: Glad that it worked! Ask me anything you need and I'll try to explain, so it's not "magic" anymore :-)